# App Insights Not Sending From Local Machine

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm attempting to send a simple alert from my local machine, and it won't go through.

```
tc = TelemetryClient(<INSTRUMENTATION KEY>)
tc.track_event("Test")
tc.flush()
```

When I call the above, the code just hangs. I can open up fiddler, and I see a number of calls to dc.services.visualstudio.com. The calls are using HTTP, and connecting with 200.

I'm using Python 3.7.2 and
`applicationinsights==0.11.9`.

Comment: If you see dc.services.visualstudio.com via fiddler, it should be sent. Can you check it on azure portal?

Comment: I've checked the Azure portal; nothing's coming through. Also, it makes multiple (hundreds, when I let it run) calls to dc.services.visualstudio.com. I'm not sure what each one is doing, since there's only a single event to send.

Comment: Where in the portal are you looking exactly?

Comment: @PeterBons - I'm checking under the logs section of the App Insights instance. I'm running a query against the customEvents table, and just grabbing everything for the last 7 days. I see _other_ logs in the table, but for whatever reason, none of my local logs will go through.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code, and it worked ok. Please nav to azure portal -> your application insights -> on the left blade, select Logs -> then write a query like `customEvents`, and select a proper time range. -> then click the "Run" button, I can see the custom events are shown there:

[image]

If the issue is still there, please try to add `time.sleep()` function after the `tc.flush()` method. The new code is as below:

```
from applicationinsights import TelemetryClient
import time

tc = TelemetryClient("the instrumentation key")
#tc = TelemetryClient("c442bc36-xxxx-45c5-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx")
tc.track_event("test event 333")
tc.flush()

time.sleep(5)

print("**completed**")
```

Please let me know if it can solve your issue or not.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but I'm still not seeing the logs coming through. I can see logs from _other_ applications, but none of my local logs are showing up. Also, the application continues to hang. I assume it's waiting on some sort of response before it'll complete.

Comment: @et_al, did you properly set the `instrumentation key`? make sure you're using the right key. Or can you please create a new project with the code, and test it again?

Comment: Yeah, I'm confident the key is set correctly. This is actually part of an Azure Function I'm writing. I see the logs coming through when I run the function in Azure, but nothing when I run it locally. The code above was a new project where I was attempting to isolate the problem.

Comment: @et_al, when running locally, have you tried to directly put the key in your code, and not read it from some config file?

Comment: Yeah, in the example above, I was just hard coding the key.

Comment: @et_al, if it still not work, please update your question with the completed code / configuration of you azure function.